# Solder or Adhesive for Wifi Module

Tags: pcb, soldering, wifi, adhesives

I am replacing a wifi module for my smart tv. I have any never done this before and want to know if I need to solder the two components together or just use an adhesive like in the old module. The first two pictures are of the old wifi module while the last one shows that the pieces I need to attach.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In my experience, it takes more force than expected to attach those connectors, maybe you are afraid to damage them? (which is reasonable) After it clicks they can still rotate in place, so if they are clicked and are stuck, but rotate, its fine. (they arent made for continuous rotation but what I mean is that it doesn't have to be immobile)

Comment: What is wrong with the antenna?  The connector is a U.FL type if that helps in your search for a replacement.

Comment: you do not need to replace the blob of silicone .... that was put there to prevent loosening during shipping ..... just click the antenna into place ..... you can loop a nylon cable tie around the board if you want extra security

Comment: Yeah, I just had to press it down. It looked fragile so I didn't want to be rough with it. The TV is working perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should not solder that miniature antenna connector.

It is actually designed to be self holding.

The manufacturer appears to have used some RTV silicone to further secure it, but it's very important to note that **this would not be hardware store RTV!!!**.  Hardware store RTV releases acetic acid which would corrode the circuit components, an alternate formulation not intended for consumer use is used inside of electronic assemblies.

We can't know the actual situation of the installation, but for many just plugging it in would be fine.  Or you could consider some kind of tape.  Even modern TV's tend to get fairly hot inside, so whatever you use would have to stand up to that.  And don't be "that guy" who uses hot glue on this.

Exercise a lot of caution during this project; even though the CRT is gone, modern TVs still often have fairly hazardous voltages present in the power supply, for example for the backlight.